# Utilizzo dell'espressione "lo sta torchiando" in luogo di "lo sta mettendo sotto torchio"

Tags: grammar

Sull'edizione online de 'La Stampa' di oggi, con riferimento agli eventi concernenti le azioni di un folle che ha tentato di uccidere alcuni passanti a Parigi, si legge:

> Quest’ultimo è l’unico ad aver parlato all’attentatore, e la polizia ***lo sta torchiando***.

Sarei interessato a sapere se il giornalista usa correttamente il verbo ***torchiare***, atteso che non ho mai sentito nessuno dire ***lo sta torchiando***, ma, invece, più volte ho sentito ***lo sta mettendo sotto torchio***.

Se, invece, l'uso giornalistico del verbo ***torchiare*** dovesse essere accettabile, sapreste spiegare il perché?

Answer (score 4):

L'utilizzo è corretto. Il significato di *torchiare* è esattamente quello di *mettere sotto torchio*, e l'esempio che citi è anche [riportato dal dizionario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/torchiare/):

> **torchiare** v. tr. [der. di *torchio*]; cfr. lat. tardo *torcŭlare*, der. di *torcŭlum*: v. *torchio*] (io *tòrchio*, ecc.). – Mettere sotto il torchio, comprimere o spremere col torchio: t. le vinacce, le olive (v. torchiatura). Con uso fig., sottoporre a domande pressanti, serrate: *il professore, all’esame, l’ha torchiato per un’ora*; ***la polizia ha torchiato a lungo l’indiziato***; anche, spremere sottoponendo a esosa pressione fiscale: *categorie sociali particolarmente torchiate dal fisco*.